# IE 9 onhashchange Delivering Undefined Event Object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a simple event listener:

```
window.onhashchange = function(e){
   alert(e.newURL);
}
```

that works great in anything but IE 9 (not testing for previous version).  In IE I'm getting an undefined event object... Any idea what I'm missing?  Is this not fully supported yet?

example here:

http://hupcapstudios.com/projects/hash.php#

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some older versions of IE9 don't pass the event as an argument to the event handler, you have to get it from `window.event`, this should work:

```
window.onhashchange = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    alert(e.newURL);
}
```

Comment: I was at least able to log the event, however e.newURL still comes up null... digging through IE's object inspector (through their dev tools) I see no newURL or oldURL properties... hmpf.

Comment: it does, my only problem with that is the newURL and oldURL were ideal for my particular application.  It seems as though I'll have to makeup some sort of history array unless someone knows where IE buries that information, if they do at all.  I gave you an upvote because you've certainly put me on the right track, I'm gonna hold off on the checkmark just in case someone knows where to get that info.